# Elasticsearch range filter not working, how can i filter price with Price range

Tags: magento2

I am try to search product listing with Price range filter in Elastic search 
but result showing 0.

Query :

```
GET magento2651_default_catalog_product/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "price.price": {
        "gte": 1,
        "lte": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data :

[image]

Let me know if anyone have idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your index mapping

This can be because field price.price is mapped as text.
This can be a reason double queries are not working.

Range queries also work on string field but by comparing characters

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: but it working fine with entity_id only problem when price have nested price field.

Comment: Can you share the mapping of the index?